# Allow DragDrop anywhere in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

Is there a way to allow Drag and Drop anywhere in a form full of controls?

The idea is to allow user to drag a file anywhere in a form in order to "load" it. I will not need any other DragDrop behavior but this.

By setting `AllowDrop=True` to the form only, I get `DragEnter` events but not `DragDrop` ones.

An idea would be to make a *topmost* panel visible on `DragEnter` and handle `DragDrop` events there, but I wonder if I miss something obvious here since I have little experience in the field.

Another Idea would be to iterate through **all** controls and subscribe to Drag-related events. I really don't like this approach, though.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, iterating the controls will work, it doesn't take much code:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        WireDragDrop(this.Controls);
    }
    private void WireDragDrop(Control.ControlCollection ctls) {
        foreach (Control ctl in ctls) {
            ctl.AllowDrop = true;
            ctl.DragEnter += ctl_DragEnter;
            ctl.DragDrop += ctl_DragDrop;
            WireDragDrop(ctl.Controls);
        }
    }

    void ctl_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        // etc..
    }

    void ctl_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e) {
        // etc..
    }
```

If you still don't like the approach then use a recognizable single drop target that the user will always hit.  Could be as simple as a label that says "Drop here".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kinds of control you have on your form. But I've tested with a Button, a GroupBox, a PictureBox and a TextBox. All these controls have `AllowDrop = false` by default. And I can drag-n-drop something from outside onto the form OK. The `DragDrop` is fired OK. Everything is OK. What is actually your problem? I guess your controls have `AllowDrop = true`.

In the case the `DragDrop` event is not fired (which I think only happens if the target is one of your Control with `AllowDrop = true`). I think the following may work. But if the target is one of your Control with `AllowDrop = true`, the effect icon is gone away.

```
public Form1(){
    InitializeComponents();
    t.Interval = 1;
    t.Tick += Tick;
}
IDataObject data;
Timer t = new Timer();
int i = 0;
private void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Text = (i++).ToString();
     if (ClientRectangle.Contains(PointToClient(new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y))) && MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
     {
        t.Stop();
        if (data != null)
        {
           //Process data here
           //-----------------               
           data = null;
        }                                
     }
     else if (MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
     {
        data = null;
        t.Stop();
     }
}

private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;
   if (data == null)
   {
       data = e.Data;
       t.Start();
   }
}
```

And I think you may have to use the loop through all the Controls to add appropriate event handlers. There is no other better way.

Answer (score -1):

In the `Drop` event.

```
string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string file in files) Console.WriteLine(file);
```

In the `DragEnter` event.

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
```

Comment: In a form full of controls, where should this be? In the form's drop event or in every single control? The question is more about how to get notified about the event, rather than actually doing something.